# changing the default private browsing page

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Is there a way to change the default page that loads up when entering private browsing/incognito? I would like to either replace the page or, preferably, add text to the current one.
Can this be done programmatically(not from a plugin/addon/extension)? if not can this be done with a plugin of some sort?
the best I could find is an addon for chrome that requires specifically toggling permissions to run in private and it will only work on remote pages and not local pages, which does not fit my needs

Comment: Could adding something like `chrome --incognito http://localhost:5000` into a script file be an alternative?

Comment: that would require me (or more correctly a user) to have a shortcut to open chrome and thats inconvenient

Comment: You are currently opening Google Chrome through a shortcut (that's how the startup menu opens Chrome). Try adding the option that @MarinosAn mentioned in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You must Use chrome-pak-customizer To unpack resources.pak
https://github.com/myfreeer/chrome-pak-customizer/releases
like

pak_mingw64.exe -u resources.pak c:\dir2

2.After this, you must change 12002.html

Content of 12002.html

```
$i18n{incognitoTabHeading}

$i18n{incognitoTabDescription} {$i18n{learnMore}} 
$i18nRaw{incognitoTabFeatures}
$i18nRaw{incognitoTabWarning}
{$i18n{learnMore}}
```

3.Pack Folder

pak_mingw64.exe -p c:\dir2\pak_index.ini c:\temp\res1.pak

4.Replace resources.pak with Your own in chrome folder!

Voila!

Answer (score -1):

I think this cannot be performed without an extension. I've tried this one: [New tab redirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna/related?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon). In the options of the extension you can set the url you need to redirect to (even a local url works) and enable the extension to work in incognito mode in the chrome options. Now when you open incognito mode it loads the url I've set.

Comment: i know i can use extensions, i was hoping there was a way to change it with minimal user interaction(enabling the extension and assigning a page)

Comment: Sorry man but you wrote " if not can this be done with a plugin of some sort?"... So I think this cannot justify a downvote...

Answer (score -1):

- Create a shortcut to chrome on desktop.
- Right click, select Properties
- In `Target` label under `Shortcut`, after `"C:..\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` just add  `-INCOGNITO WWW.GOOGLE.COM` without quotes and click Apply.
  You may add link to any page you wish to open in incognito instead of `WWW.GOOGLE.COM`

Comment: this would require the user to open incognito using a shortcut, unfortunately this is not what i'm looking for